# didUpdateLocations instead of didUpdateToLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

With the release of iOS6 Apple wants us to use didUpdateLocations instead of didUpdateToLocation. Can anyone explain how to properly use didUpdateLocations?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I asume you used the following delegate to get the last position?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

The delegate above is deprecated in iOS 6. Now the following should be used:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

In order to get the last position, simply get the last object of the array:

```
[locations lastObject]
```

In other words, `[locations lastObject]` (new delegate) equals `newLocation` (old delegate) .

Comment: @Anne what about old location?

Comment: @S.J you can get the old location by saving it from a previous call to the delegate method.  There is an example at the end of the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10198249/1693173)

Comment: Wouldn't the oldLocation object be the second to last object in the array?

Comment: Is this still CLLocation object? or an NSString?

Comment: @windsound Yes  [locations lastObject] is CLLocation object.

Comment: but how we can extract coordinate from the array i mean longitude and lattitude?

Answer (score 65):

None of the other answers here explain why there is a locations array and how to properly use the new didUpdateLocations: array that is provided.

The purpose of deprecating the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` and sending an NSArray of locations instead is to reduce power consumption when running in the background.

Starting with iPhone 5, the GPS chip has the capability to store locations for a period of time and then deliver them all at once in an array.  This is called deferred location updates.  This allows the main CPU to sleep for a longer period of time while in the background.  It means iOS doesn't have to start the main CPU for every position update, the CPU can sleep, while the GPS chip collects locations.

You can check for this capability using the [`deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable) method.  If available you can enable it using `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:` method.  Some conditions apply, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509263/1693173) for details.

Comment: This was the answer I really wanted to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

It gives you array of objects to access last location you can use

```
[locations lastObject]
```

from this delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Comment: what about old location? how to get that?

Comment: That (old location) is no longer provided in this iOS6 call.  I generally store the most current location in an instance variable called `old_location` if I need to compare.  Upon arrival of the new location, i compare to the instance variable `old_location` and do something...or not.  Then I update that `old_location` to the new one just given to me.  This keeps `old_location` in sync with last-known location.

Answer (score 7):

This is how the method can be implemented to work similarly as the deprecated one

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = locations.lastObject;
    CLLocation *oldLocation;
    if (locations.count > 1) {
        oldLocation = locations[locations.count - 2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you support both iOS 5 and 6, you should call

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations,
```

from the older

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

function, by building an array of locations.

Answer (score 2):

It is noteworthy that the array of CLLocation objects returned by locationManager:didUpdateLocations: may or may not include a former location.  In other words, there may be on rare occasions only one location in the array.  Use the following to check, and if there is more than one object we can retrieve the most recent prior location:

```
int objCount = [locations count];
if (objCount > 1) {
    CLLocation *oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:objCount - 1];
}
```

As there will be at least one object in the array, retrieving the current location is done by requesting the last object in the array.  Even if the last object is the only object, that's Ok:

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
```

Keep in mind that because this is an array, oldLocation in the example shown above will not necessarily be the one you're looking for.  This depends on how you setDistanceFilter: and desiredAccuracy: properties, as those properties will impact how your locations array is populated.  The desired oldLocation may be buried deeper in the array.