# How to work with deferred location iOS 6?

Tags: xcode, location, ios6

I am trying to use the new iOS 6 feature of deffered location updates but keep on getting this error :

> didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError :Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=11 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 11.)"

I am using the following code:

```
- (DeviceAPI *) init
    {
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     [locationManager setDelegate:self];
     [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
     [locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:(CLLocationDistance)100000     timeout:(NSTimeInterval)100000];

    return self;
 }
```

And this `callback` function :

```
- (void)locationManager:    (CLLocationManager *)   manager
                        didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError :%@", [error description]);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Error 11 for `kCLErrorDomain` is `kCLErrorDeferredFailed`. See documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CLError).

Comment: I found this looking for iOS 10 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498899/deferredlocationupdatesavailable-returns-no-in-ios-10

Answer (score 8):

According to the Apple Developer Forums for the iOS 6.0 SDK, deferred location updates are only available:

- on iPhone 5 hardware
- running iOS 6.0 or higher
- desired accuracy set to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` or `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` because this **requires** a GPS chip. An iPad without cellular data does not have a GPS Chip.
- call the "startUpdatingLocation" method
- wait for location updates to come in at approximately 1 per second
- then begin deferring updates

<s>See: https://devforums.apple.com/message/751974#751974</s>

See docs: [`allowDeferredLocationUpdates(untilTraveled:timeout:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdates)

So sounds like you need iPhone 5 hardware, and to wait for location updates to come in at 1Hz.

Additionally, as another poster mentioned, you'd need to implement the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method in your delegate.

> The most common place to call this [`allowDeferredLocationUpdates`] method is in your delegate’s
>   `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` method. After processing any
>   new locations, call this method if you want to defer future updates
>   until the distance or time criteria are met. If new events arrive and
>   your app is in the background, the events are cached and their
>   delivery is deferred appropriately.
>
> <sub>From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdates). I've added notes inside `[]`</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set location in your info.plist UIBackgroundModes field?

Comment: Yes I have... I have also found out that [CLLocationManager deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable] returns FALSE. This occurs both on ios6 simulator and iPhone 4 IOS6 device. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing I have found that deferred updates only work in iOS 6.0.1 or greater, but not 6.0. I tested on 2 phones 1 which I updated and 1 which I left using 6.0 for testing reasons. I believe this is the reason why the simulator doesn't work and if your phone isn't updated yet it is likely why that isn't working either.

Also make sure you implement

– locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

rather than the now deprecated

– locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

as it is required for use with deferred location updates.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout: set the distance filter to kCLDistanceFilterNone, then it will work.

Answer (score -1):

I found this description in one Framework sample for [CLRegion initCircularRegionWithCenter] call:

"If the overlay's radius is too large, registration fails automatically, so clamp the radius to the max value."