# Developer/API features iphone 5c vs 5s/5

Tags: ios, iphone

I am currently developing my first commercial iOS-App and I need a second test device, so I can test iOS 7 on my iPhone 4S and iOS 8 on the iPhone 5/5c/5s.

I know of differences between 4S and 5 with the same iOS version, [e.g. deferred location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20375358/3085985) - are there such differences for iPhone 5c vs iPhone 5s or can I just take the 5c or even 5 without any worries?

Comment: The 5S is 64 bit and the 5C and all versions below arent

Comment: The iPhone 5S has a [64 bit]() processor and [Touch ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014520-CH1)