# didUpdateLocations keeps calling every second with deferred updates

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to implement the deferred location updates to have a better battery consumption.
I'm starting my location manager like this :

```
- (void)initCoreLocation
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
    self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;

    //Très important pour iOS9 !
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)]) {
        self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=YES;
    }

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

And starting deferred update like this way:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

    if (!self.deferringUpdates) {
        [self.locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:CLLocationDistanceMax timeout:30];
        self.deferringUpdates = YES;
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:(NSError *)error { // Stop deferring updates
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    NSLog(@"didFinishDeferredUpdates");
    self.deferringUpdates = NO;
}
```

I have `didFinishDeferredUpdates` log every 30 seconds, however `didUpdateLocations` keeps calling every second, removing any try to optimise the battery consumption. Is it supposing to the location manager to call the `didUpdateLocations` every 30 seconds ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not having the right approach as `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled()` tells the GPS hardware to store new locations internally until the specified distance or timeout conditions are met.

From the iOS Developer Library:

> If your app is in the foreground, the location manager does not defer the deliver of events but does monitor for the specified criteria. If your app moves to the background before the criteria are met, the location manager may begin deferring the delivery of events. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging?

As stated in the answer here: [ios deferred location updates fail to defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351108/ios-deferred-location-updates-fail-to-defer)

> Deferred updates are delivered only when the system enters a low power state. Deferred updates do not occur during debugging because Xcode prevents your app from sleeping and thus prevents the system from entering that low power state.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you only need one of them at one time, change the call in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`

```
- (**void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Need to stop regular updates first
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    // Only monitor significant changes
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: We need the `startUpdatingLocation` to make work the deferred location updates .

Comment: remove the line `self.deferringUpdates = NO`

Comment: The question is about deferred location updates, not significant location changes. SLC does not use GPS and there is nowhere to defer locations to. It uses wifi and cell-tower triangulation to monitor for significant changes. 

At least in my experience, SLC and DLU don't work well together.