# didUpdateLocations delegate method not call in iOS 5.1 and earlier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am using CoreLocation Framework for getting latitude and longitude in my project.

I have implement this delegate method in my .m file

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

   NSLog(@"Locations : %@", locations); 
}
```

But in iOS 5.0 & 5.1, this method is not call.
and in iOS 6.0 or later it's call properly.
so how to call this method in iOS 5.0 or later.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602463/didupdatelocations-instead-of-didupdatetolocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didUpdateLocations:` did not exist in ios 5 or earlier.  If you want to support those ios version then just use the deprecated `didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation`.  Even though it is deprecated it still works in ios 6 and 7. That's the simplest solution.

You could have delegate methods for both, but that gets more complicated to manage. If you don't need to build track logs in the background then you don't really need `didUpdateLocations:`  it was created to save battery power while collecting multiple points when running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer...This method for iOS 5 (deprecated on iOS 6)and old version.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

This method for iOS 6 and later version..

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html

As you can see `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` is available only in `iOS 6.0` and later.

You can always get the recent updated location from

```
CLLocationManger's location
```

property.