# iOS 8 Location Service not working in spite of adding NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Tags: ios, ios8, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I'm using `iOS8 [8.0.2]` and no matter what I try I cant get the `CLLocationManager` to work.

I added the following lines to `info.plist`.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app use location services.</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app use location services.</string>
```

In my implementation file :

```
In ViewDidLoad : 

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

But none of the below methods are being called.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

What is that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602463/didupdatelocations-instead-of-didupdatetolocation).

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

The above delegate was deprecated in iOS 6. Used the following instead:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

**EDIT**

Do not set `mapView.showUserLocation` to YES before receiving authorization via `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Set it this way:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    self.mapView.showUserLocation = YES;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Did you add Core Location framework to your project?

Comment: Yes.. I did. I deleted the app and when I ran, it gave me this warning : Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Comment: Did you add CLLocationManagerDelegate to @interface in .h file?

Comment: Also, set `mapView.showUserLocation = YES` only in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`, not before authorization is received.

Comment: Tried that. No change.

Comment: Try to run your code on device also check your app name under privacy->Location Service

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698685/1021238) brought me to the solution after struggling for a long time.

You need to make `locationManager` a property of your controller.

I should note that this occurred to me with Swift.