# Not getting authorization for location iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I've tried looking at other solutions such as: [requestWhenInUseAuthorization() not Work in iOS 8 With NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription Key in Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681951/requestwheninuseauthorization-not-work-in-ios-8-with-nslocationwheninuseusaged)

But I can't get authorization prompt to get location.

That person's issue in that other question was that he had is manager inside his `viewDidLoad`, I do not, but still an authorization prompt is not showing up. I've updated my plist:

[image: gyazo.com/b66946b9976aa226a21c0bf6e3817e3a]

and have my manager outside of my `viewDidLoad`:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MapKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()


var player = AVPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    println("Got to end of locationmanager")
    //playentryaudio() // User plugged in mic -- start playing entry audio.
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("Got to locationmngsr")
    var userlocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees = userlocation.coordinate.latitude

    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = userlocation.coordinate.longitude

    println(latitude)
    println(longitude)
} //snip rest of code
```

Since It's not getting auth, It's never hitting the locationManager function.

Answer (score 1):

The prompt only shows if `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined`. If the user previously denied access, you won't see the prompt anymore. You should check the status before `self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. If it shows anything but `.NotDetermined`, look at the location settings for the app and the device.

If the status is `.NotDetermined` and the prompt still does not show, I would double check spelling of the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Comment: I'll check, but I'm running this in the emulator and never even got the request, unless the emulator sets the status to denied by default.

Comment: The emulator does not set the status to denied by default, but I think it would be a good idea to check the actual status programmatically to rule out one possibility.

Comment: That if statement returned true (Not Determined). I tried printing `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` to see the actual status, but it prints saying that It's a 'enum value'.

Comment: In that case everything shown looks just fine. One thing I do not see though is the full name of the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` string. Are you sure the spelling is correct and there are no extra spaces at the end?

Comment: Yep -- It's an exact match.