# I want to get current location but cant fetch

Tags: ios

Can't get current location from my code:

```
(IBAction)getdetails:(id)sender {
    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
(void)locationmanager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        _latitudelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        _latitudelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
```

Comment: Please solve this problm..I also add tw frame work core  location,mapkit..

Comment: Please format your question properly. Use `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602463/didupdatelocations-instead-of-didupdatetolocation)

Comment: Please update your question with the problem you are facing, and also see it is properly formatted, so that people who wish to help can do so.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 you need to do two extra things to get location working:

1. Add a following key to your Info.plist: 
   `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
2. Request authorization from the location manager asking it to start.

   ```
   [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];    // or 
   [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
   ```

You can get more info from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

For Important info on CoreLocation you should also have a look at this [Blog](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)

Comment: This is a correct solution.