# Lat,Long values are not accurate to the current location in iphone

Tags: core-location, mkmapview

I am new to IOS now I am developing location app i am not getting correct latitude,longitude values while running my app in iPhone.. it gives me too far lat,long values to the current location why it shows me these values can anyone tell me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with CLLocation method distanceFromLocation: Inaccurate results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184802/trouble-with-cllocation-method-distancefromlocation-inaccurate-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it....

Set Delegate CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
CLLocation *startLocation;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *currentLatitude;
    NSString *currentLongitude;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    startLocation = nil;
 }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc] 
                   initWithFormat:@"%g", 
                   newLocation.coordinate.latitude];



    currentLongitude = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithFormat:@"%g",
                    newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

   NSLog(@"%@",currentLatitude);
   NSLog(@"%@",currentLongitude);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```